# Array of chars in hex format to integer?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-conversion

I have an API which returns a byte[] over the network which represents information about a device.

It is in format 15ab1234cd\r\n where the first 2 characters are a HEX representation of the amount of data in the message.

I am aware I can convert this to a string via `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString`, and then use `Convert.ToInt32(string.Substring(0, 2), 16)` to achieve this. However the whole thing stays a byte array throughout the life of the whole program I am writing, and I don't want to convert to a string just for the purpose of getting the packet length.

Any suggestions of converting array of chars in hex format to an int in C#?

Comment: Are you just looking to extract the first two bytes and turn that into an integer? You could grab the first two bytes then and just do a GetString() on those, then convert.

Comment: So in your example 15 means that you have a message of 21 char after the first two bytes?

Comment: @Steve - yes that is what it would mean.

Comment: @Marius - yes I could get a string from the first 2 bytes, but I would also have to get it for the last 2 bytes as well (I was trying to generalize my question which would work for both cases), so I might as well do the conversion once.

Comment: I suppose you could write a function that manually maps `byte` to a number for the relevant ASCII codes (`'0'`-`'9'`, `'A'`-`'F'`, and `'a'`-`'f'`, so 22 in total), but it's probably not worth reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @T.C. I agree about not worth reinventing the wheel. I was more looking to see if there is an API call I am missing.

Comment: @esac No there is no built-in api. You could have written that a few-lines code 10 times in the same duration while preparing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the first two values are valid hexadecimal characters (0-9, A-Z, a-z), it is possible to convert to a hex value using logical operators.

```
int GetIntFromHexBytes(byte[] s, int start, int length)
{
   int ret = 0;
   for (int i = start; i < start+length; i++)
   {
      ret <<= 4;
      ret |= (byte)((s[i] & 0x0f) + ((s[i] & 0x40) >> 6) * 9);
   }
   return ret;
}
```

(This works because `c & 0x0f` returns the 4 least significant bits, and will range from 0-9 for the values '0'-'9', and from 1 - 6 for both capital and lowercase letters ('a' - 'z' and 'A' - 'Z').  `s[i] & 0x40` is 0 for numeric characters, and 0x40 for alpha characters; shifting right six characters provides a value of 0 for numeric characters and 1 for alphabetic characters.  Shifting left and multiplying by 9 will add a bias of 9 for alpha characters to map A-F and a-f from 1-6 to 10-15.)

Given the byte array:

```
byte[] b = { (byte)'7', (byte)'f', (byte)'1', (byte)'c' };
```

Calling `GetIntFromHexBytes(b, 0, 2)` will return 127 (0x7f), the first two bytes of the array, as required.

As a caution: this approach does no bounds checking.  A check can be added in the loop if needed to ensure that the input bytes are valid hex characters.

Answer (score 2):

There is no .Net provided function that does it. Converting first 2 bytes to string with [Encoding.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is very readable (possibly not most performant):

```
 var hexValue = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData, 0, 2);
 var intValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16);
```

You can easily write conversion code (map `'0'-'9'` and `'a'-'f'` / `'A'-'F'` ranges to corresponding integer value and add together.

Here is one-statement conversion strictly for entertainment purposes. The resulting lambda (before `((byte)'0',(byte)'A')` in sample takes 2 byte arguments assuming them to be ASCII characters and convert into integer.

```
((Func<Func<char,int>, Func<byte, byte, int>>)
    (charToInt=> (c, c1)=> 
       charToInt(char.ToUpper((char)c)) * 16 + charToInt(char.ToUpper((char)c1))))
  ((Func<char, int>)(
      c => c >= '0' && c <='9' ? c-'0' : c >='A' && c <= 'F' ? c - 'A' + 10 : 0))
 ((byte)'0',(byte)'A')
```